# Is this method of protecting a signing certificate secure?

Tags: code-signing, digital-certificate, pfx

Is it secure to encapsulate "signtool" within an EXE program? This program relies on a password-protected PFX file nearby, and knows its password to access its private key. The certificate is never in the store of the machine that does the signing.

My thinking is that even if the PFX file itself is distributed freely, unauthorized use to sign something (outside of using this EXE) would fail, since no-one would know its password.

I realize unauthorized use of the EXE is not preventable, but it also logs its every use so at least we'd have an audit trail.

I'm trying to improve upon what was done with the prior certificate, which was mass-distribution of the PFX file and its password...ugh.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I received no answers, but I put this into practice, and it seems to work well.  Because the code needs to know the PFX password, I construct it out-of-order rather than putting a string directly into the code (to guard against reverse engineering) and then I clip out those parts before storing it in source control.